# Change site currency along with product prices

Tags: magento-1.9, price, currency

Currently site is using euro and all product prices is in euro. 
How can we switch whole site to use usd so that all products also will change their prices according to currency exchange rate ?

Comment: I have an idea: change your base currency then use bulk price update extension to update all products price by currency rate. Here is free bulk price update extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-update-all-product-prices.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another store view with different currency(usd), make this store view default and reindex. It worked.